# How comes, that i get an ArgumentException for existing Key on Children.Add?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin

i use an inheritance of AbsoluteLayout to avoid the Children in the Maincode for reasons.

So i have an own Add Method:

```
    internal void Add(View control, Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        if (!this.Children.Contains(control)) this.Children.Add(control, rectangle);
    }
```

The Xamarin-UWP Version works flawless, but
i also use Ooui to use it for ASP.NET which works great.

But there i get following Exception:

```
An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.GetValue(BindableProperty property)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.get_Padding()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated(Double width, Double height)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated(Double width, Double height)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize(Double width, Double height)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Bounds(Rectangle value)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Layout(Rectangle bounds)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion(VisualElement child, Rectangle region)
   at Xamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutChildren(Double x, Double y, Double width, Double height)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated(Double width, Double height)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated(Double width, Double height)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.ForceLayout()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.InvalidateLayout()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnInternalAdded(View view)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.InternalChildrenOnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
   at Xamarin.Forms.ObservableWrapper`2.Add(TRestrict item)
   at Xamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout.AbsoluteElementCollection.Add(View view, Rectangle bounds, AbsoluteLayoutFlags flags)
   at DT_AbsoluteLayout.Add(View control, Rectangle rectangle) in DT_AbsoluteLayout.cs
```

I tried printing all Ids of every Children before, but it was not present.

What can i do or try to fix that problem?
I tried different Assembly and Visual Studio Versions.
Using the Children directly caused the same Error.

The View which causes that exception is always the same one and it will be placed, but at the wrong position.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: That wont be possible ... even minimalistic, it would show too much that i am allowed to show :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem, that the LayoutChildren Class in the Layouts are not locking the Childrens ... after adapting the Methods and locking Children, the error seem to not appear anymore:

```
       protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
        {
            lock (this.Children)
            {
                bool repeat = false;
                do
                {
                    try
                    {
                        base.LayoutChildren(x, y, width, height);
                        repeat = false;
                    }
                    catch (Exception tcem_ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[ERROR] "+tcem_ex.Message);
                        repeat = true;
                    }
                } while (repeat);
            }
        }
```